# Can you get a repository's license in Gitlab through the REST API?

Tags: java, rest, gitlab

In Github, when you set up a project, you can specify the license under which the project is and it's later possible to check it in the UI, or get it via the REST API.

Is the same thing possible in Gitlab? Is there a Java library I can use for this? I've been going over the REST API, but I can't seem to find such a thing. It also doesn't seem to be possible to configure this when creating/setting up the repository.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding flag license in project API.

With this option enabled you will get "license_url" and "license" in your response json. Also about the question, having License file in a folder, not in your root - gitlab will think that you don't have license for your project and fetching with license flag will give you NULL.

License format won't matter, even though creating from template and try to add format (.txt, .bat, .md, etc) is hard, due to with every written character you will be driven from license_name form field, so I think most repos will have just LICENSE in the end.

For example get license from gitlab-org/gitlab repository (id 278964):

```
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964?license=yes
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 278964,
  "description": "GitLab is an open source end-to-end software development platform with built-in version control, issue tracking, code review, CI/CD, and more. Self-host GitLab on your own servers, in a container, or on a cloud provider.",
  "name": "GitLab",
  "name_with_namespace": "GitLab.org / GitLab",
  ...
  "license_url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/LICENSE",
  "license": {
    "key": "other",
    "name": "Other",
    "nickname": "LICENSE",
    "html_url": "http://choosealicense.com/licenses/other/",
    "source_url": null
  },
}
```

Comment: [Indeed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/v15.6.1-ee/doc/api/projects.md#get-single-project) :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a GitLab API for this:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/managed_licenses.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/templates/licenses.html

All the Clients are listed here and there are a couple of Java ones:
https://about.gitlab.com/partners/#api-clients

Comment: Hm... Why are they called managed licenses and what's with the whitelisting and blacklisting of licenses? I'm looking for a way to get the license of the project, not its dependencies. Is this he correct thing?

Comment: TBH I've never used this, but my guess is that your company might define a policy which Open-Source licenses are ok to use in your code and which are not. Some licenses are more prohibitive (like GNU) and some are less (like BSD). For example GPL requires you to open source your code if you use a library under GPL. Hence if you have a private project, and you can't open your sources, you might put for example GPL into blacklist. Next time your Dev uses a dependency published under GPL, GitLab will probably not allow that. But again - this is purely my speculations.

Comment: I'm looking for something different. I'm looking for what the license of a project is. In Github, you can check it. For example: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/blob/master/LICENSE . (In this case it's in the code base itself, but you can check it through the Github REST API). I'm trying to find out, if the Gitlab API has the same thing.

Comment: Got it. As LICENSE is just a fine in repo, why don't you just fetch it? If you want by API - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html

Comment: Because the file name could be all sorts of things like `LICENSE`, `LICENSE.TXT`, `Licence.txt`, `LICENSE.md`, etc, and it can sometimes be placed in directories nested below the root. It is an option, I've been trying to avoid having to look into myself and was therefore hoping it would be supported by the REST API, like it is in Github.

Comment: How does GitHub knows that where are the licenses?

Comment: When you create the repository, you can configure this. You may, or may not have a license file in it. If you have a license file, it will map it and add a link to it for you, so when you browse the project and click on the license at the top, it will redirect you to the actual license file that it has identified. I was expecting Gitlab to have the same sort of functionality.

Comment: GitLab indeed has the same functionality

Comment: Would you mind illustrating how to do it? Thanks! :)